# represent helm chart values.yaml in helmfile.yaml

Tags: helmfile

I am trying to represent the following in the helmfile.yaml but I am getting an error. Can anyone help me to set it up?

values.yaml

```
extraVolumes:
 - name: google-cloud-key
   secret:
     secretName: gcloud-auth
```

I tried the following in helmfile.yaml

```
repositories:
  - name: loki 
    url: https://grafana.github.io/loki/charts

releases:
  - name: loki
    namespace: monitoring
    chart: loki/loki
    set: 
    - name: extraVolumes.name
      value: google-cloud-key
    - name: extraVolumes.secret.secretName
      value: gcloud-auth
```

The error I am getting is

```
coalesce.go:160: warning: skipped value for extraVolumes: Not a table.
```

I also tried with the following in helmfile.yaml

```
    - name: extraVolumes.name[]
      value: google-cloud-key
```

This gave me the following error

```
Error: failed parsing --set data: key map "extraVolumes" has no value
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Helmfile has two ways to provide values to the charts it installs.  You're using `set:`, which mimics the finicky `helm install --set` option.  However, Helmfile also supports `values:`, which generally maps to `helm install -f`.  Helmfile `values:` supports two extensions: if a filename in the list ends in `*.gotmpl` then the values file itself is processed as a template file before being given to Helm; or you can put inline YAML-syntax values directly in `helmfile.yaml`.

This last option is probably easiest.  Instead of using `set:`, use `values:`, and drop that block of YAML directly into `helmfile.yaml`.

```yaml
releases:
  - name: loki
    namespace: monitoring
    chart: loki/loki
    values:                         # not `set:`
      - extraVolumes:               # inline YAML content as a single list item
          - name: google-cloud-key
            secret:
              secretName: gcloud-auth
```

`values:` is set to a list of either filenames or inline mappings.  If you're not deeply familiar with YAML syntax, this means you need to put a `-` list-item indicator before the inline YAML block.  If you already have a list of `values:` files you can add this additional item into the list wherever appropriate.